# Where does started service do after it has been started?

Tags: android, service

I read up on started services and saw that it has a callback method named

```
onStartCommand()
```

which is called "when another component, such as an activity, requests that the service be started, by calling startService()" and that "Once this method executes, the service is started and can run in the background indefinitely". I am confused about what "run in the background indefinitely" means. I made an application that tracked the number of times onStartCommand() is called in the service and saw that that method is only called once(when the service is started from startService). After the started service starts, does it just sit around in the background and do nothing until you stop it? I don't see any other callbacks to implement after the started service is started to do some behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the service keeps executing until stopped. If the code you give it to run reaches completion without stopping the service, it will sit and wait for a lifecycle callback to be invoked.

Comment: So startCommand runs to completion, and then the service sits idle until another liecycle callback like startCommand(saw that it could be called again even after the service has been created) or OnDestroy?